# Can't use binary search with Object Arraylist?

Tags: java, binary-search

I tried using a binary search with an Arraylist  and it gave me this message:

The method binarySearch(List>, T) in the type Collections is not applicable for the arguments (ArrayList, String)

Here's the code:

```
ArrayList <Object> a = new ArrayList <Object> ();
String date = JOptionPane.showInputDialog(null, "Please enter the date.")
int index = Collections.binarySearch(a, date);
```

The binary search should return the position of a specific date from an array (a) of several dates. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Show us the declaration of `a`, please.

Answer (score 3):

To perform a binary search, your `Collection` must be sorted. In order to sort something, this something needs to have a well-defined order. That is, what the [`Comparable<T>`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Comparable.html) interface is for. `Object` does not implement `Comparable<Object>` and therefore a `List` of `Object` cannot be sorted (ther are no criteria to sort them).
Please look at the [API](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Collections.html#binarySearch-java.util.List-T-) for mor details.

Comment: k thanks. The problem is, my array is going to contain both doubles and strings, so how would I go about searching the array for a specific string among doubles and strings?

Comment: @Vctrm6 you mean your `ArrayList`, right? I think your algorithm is broken by design. Either store the `double`s as Strings in your `ArrayList<String>` and re-parse them into doubles (dirty work-around) or overthink your design, so you do not need to store `String`s and `double`s in the same list.

Answer (score 2):

`a` should be a `List<String>`, not a `List<Object>`.  `Collections.binarySearch` expects the list to contain the same type you are searching for, and the lowest type in common -- `Object` -- is not `Comparable`, so it cannot be used for a binary search.

Comment: Ok thanks. The problem is, my array is going to contain both doubles and strings, so how would I go about searching the array for a specific string among doubles and strings?

Comment: You can't use `binarySearch`, then.  You could use `indexOf`, and accept that it'll take O(n).  (But frankly, mixing two different types in the same list like that is a huge design smell that says you're doing something deeply wrong.)

Comment: @Vctrm6 you could have posted this as comment under your question instead of asking both of us the same. Anyway, you got the same basic answer: bad design.

Answer (score 0):

Object does not implement `Comaparable<Object>`.  You must provide `Comparator<Object>`.

```
    ArrayList <Object> a = new ArrayList<>();
    // add elements to a.
    Comparator<Object> comparator = (x, y) -> x.toString().compareTo(y.toString());
    Collections.sort(a, comparator);
    String date = JOptionPane.showInputDialog(null, "Please enter the date.")
    int index = Collections.binarySearch(a, date, comparator);
```

`comparatoer` in this code is only an example.