# How to use `Collections.binarySearch()` to do a binary search though an ArrayList of objects?

Tags: java, comparator, binary-search

I have tried all the answers from the related questions, like following:

[Implement binary search using the `Collections.binarySearch` signature](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40196002/implement-binary-search-using-the-collections-binarysearch-signature)

[Can't use binary search with Object Arraylist?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30743531/cant-use-binary-search-with-object-arraylist)

But none of them have worked for me.

The thing is that I want to do `binarySearch()` to find an object with a particular attribute in an `ArrayList`.

I am using the following code for this:

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Collections;
import java.util.Comparator;

public class SearchingThread extends Thread {

    private String search;
    private ArrayList<Vehicle> vehicles;

    public SearchingThread(String search, ArrayList<Vehicle> vehicles) {
        this.search = search;
        this.vehicles = vehicles;
    }

    public void run() {

        Comparator<Vehicle> comp = new Comparator<Vehicle>() {

            @Override
            public int compare(Vehicle o1, Vehicle o2) {
                return o1.getModel().compareTo(o2.getModel());
            }

        };

        int index = Collections.binarySearch(vehicles, search, comp);



    }

}
```

Here `search` is the variable with the `model` that I want to search in the ArrayList `vehicles`.

I am getting the following error for this:

> The method binarySearch(List, T, Comparator) in the type Collections is not applicable for the arguments (ArrayList, String, Comparator)

I am not able to use it, can anyone help me understand the cause and solution to the error.

**Edit:**

Sorry for not posting this before, sorting is not an issue. I have sorted the array list accordingly beforehand.

Comment: Just for the record: you understand that a prerequisite for binary search is that your array/list is already sorted? Is that the case here?

Comment: "I was too lazy" you are supremely lazy if you can't be bothered to do s/eihcle/ehicle/g.

Comment: @AndyTurner yes :)

Comment: @GhostCat apologies, see the edited question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[`Collections#binarySearch`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Collections.html#binarySearch-java.util.List-T-java.util.Comparator-) searches a `List` for the same type of value that the list holds. Here, you're trying to search a list of vehicles with a string, and thus getting the error your shared.
One approach is to create a fake vehicle just so its model can be searched:

```
Vehicle modelDummy = new Vehicle();
modelDummy.setModel(search);
int index = Collections.binarySearch(vehicles, modelDummy, comp);
```

Note that in order to use `binarySearch` like that the list must be sorted according to the `Comparator` you provide (i.e., sorted according to the model in this case). If this assumption is not true, you'll have to use an O(n) search. E.g.:

```
Vehicle vehicle = vehicles.stream().filter(v -> v.getModel().eqauls(search)).findFirst();
```

Answer (score 0):

Create a view of the list:

```
List<String> view = new AbstractList<String>() {
  @Override public int size() {
    return vehicles.size();
  }

  @Override public String get(int i) {
    return vehicles.get(i).getModel();
  }
};
```

Then apply binary search to the view.

```
int index = Collections.binarySearch(view, search);
```

Note that whilst it would work using an anonymous class, like this, it would be better to define a named class (e.g. a nested class, or even a local class), in order that it can both `extend AbstractList` and `implement RandomAccess`, so that the binary search knows it can access efficiently by index.

Answer (score 0):

Since this branch contains both correct solutions and it is both forbidden to use in my task, I will write my own, at the same time I will ask people to evaluate whether it is correct (the decision was made, tests passed)?
If you looking for vehicles by model(String model):

```
int index = Collections.binarySearch(vehicles, model, new Comparator<Object>(){
        @Override
        public int compare(Object o1, Object o2) {
            Vehicle veh = (Vehicle)o1;
            String str = (String) o2;
            return veh.getModel().compareTo(str);
        }
    });
```

What do you think?

Comment: OR one more - consider search value in sorting (output them always on top, for example),  without binarySearch().